# how can I use a variable as a variable name in this bash script

Tags: bash, variables

I am currently trying to make a variable name that would consist of another variable

```
while [ "$countf" -le 9 ]; do
                    vname=$( echo fcp"$countf" )
                    $vname=$( awk -F, -vs="\$fc$countf" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~"^"s"$"){print i;exit;}}{print "not found"}' <<< $first_line )
                    countf=$(( countf + 1 ))
            done
```

although when I go to execute the the script that includes the code, something along the lines of the following is outputted:

```
fcp1=not: command not found
```

fcp1 being the content of the vname variable. I've tried several different solutions but have not gotten anything to work yet as of right now, if someone could point out what I am doing wrong though I would really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: why do you need this? Why don't you just call it `p1p2` or directly `cat1`?

Comment: Repeat of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462936/why-can-i-not-save-the-output-of-this-awk-statement-to-a-variable by same user, just 1 hour ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
eval cat$p2="something"
```

without the quotes around the variable name.