# why can I not save the output of this awk statement to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I am currently trying to make a variable name that would consist of another variable

```
while [ "$countf" -le 9 ]; do
    vname=$( echo fcp"$countf" )
    $vname=$( awk -F, -vs="\$fc$countf" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~"^"s"$"){print i;exit;}}{print "not found"}' <<< $first_line )
    countf=$(( countf + 1 ))
done
```

although when I go to execute the the script that includes the code, something along the lines of the following is outputted:

```
fcp1=not: command not found
```

fcp1 being the content of the vname variable. I've tried several different solutions but have not gotten anything to work yet as of right now, if someone could point out what I am doing wrong though I would really appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've made a mistake, instead of

```
$vname=$(... )
```

you should use :

```
vname=$(... )
```

You can't use `$` in the left of assignation like this.

A workaround is to use `declare` if you want to do *indirect variable references* :

```
$ x=var
$ declare $x=test
$ echo $var
test
```

**NOTE**

As mentioned in discussion in this thead, don't use `eval` to do this. `eval` is a common misspelling of *evil*. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: the variable name is a variable itself though, wouldnt taking away the $ cause it to not expand?

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks! will have to remember that eval == evil in the future lol

Answer (score 0):

You need to use eval if you're going to build a variable name from parts like that:

```
$ cat tst.sh
countf=0
while (( $countf <= 2 ))
do
    vname="fcp${countf}"
    eval $vname="\$(date)"

    countf=$(( countf + 1 ))
    sleep 1
done

echo "$fcp0"
echo "$fcp1"
echo "$fcp2"

$ ./tst.sh
Mon Nov 19 21:22:05 CST 2012
Mon Nov 19 21:22:06 CST 2012
Mon Nov 19 21:22:08 CST 2012
```

but you should seriously consider an array instead:

```
$ cat tst.sh
countf=0
while (( $countf <= 2 ))
do
    fcpArr[$countf]="$(date)"

    countf=$(( countf + 1 ))
    sleep 1
done

echo "${fcpArr[0]}"
echo "${fcpArr[1]}"
echo "${fcpArr[2]}"

$ ./tst.sh
Mon Nov 19 21:22:48 CST 2012
Mon Nov 19 21:22:50 CST 2012
Mon Nov 19 21:22:51 CST 2012
```

Comment: I disagree, that's why I propose `declare`. `eval` should be avoided when not absolutely necessary. 'eval' is a common misspelling of 'evil'. If eval is the answer, surely you are asking the wrong question. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: You understand that I'm suggesting using an array rather than eval, right? Of course eval should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I suggest not even introducing `eval` into the conversation if there is a better alternative.

Comment: What's this `eval` thing you speak of?  I must try it out, and use it in ALL my scripts!